# Overriding the product template, where to find the default file?

Tags: template

Inherited a project and am not familiar with Magento enough to know where to find things.

There are a bunch of errors on our product detail page (app/design/frontend/{name}/{dir}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product).

Just as a quick example, in my browser's console I see errors that the Product is not defined, VerienForm is not defined and so on. These are javascript errors for missing objects, for whatever reason. What I would like to do is compare this template to working/known product view page.

Is this a completely custom file or is there a default/sample provided?

Aaron

Comment: what you want to you explain shortly...

Comment: Just trying to fix an existing product template/view. Want to know if there is a default or sample product view to compare against either from magento or from the community.